# How to update another text box while typing in access 2007 form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox

I have a few text boxes which have to be filled with numeric values from 0 to 100. Below them there is another text box which stands for a total (the sum of the values from the text boxes above). How can I update the sum text box while typing in any of the other text boxes above?

Comment: could you use a label for the calculated total instead of an editable text box?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is problematic due to the asinine requirement in Access that you have to set focus to text areas before you can get their value. I would recommend you change your design so that the text field is updated in response to a button click instead of on change.

If you want to go the update-on-change route, you would attach change events to each of the addend text fields. The event handlers would need to save the caret position/selection length, update the sum in the output text field, and restore the caret position. You need to save/restore the caret position because this is lost when the focus changes.

Here's an example for two text fields (txt1 and txt2). The output field is named txtOutput.

```
Private Sub txt1_Change()
    Dim caret_position As Variant

    caret_position = Array(txt1.SelStart, txt1.SelLength)

    UpdateSum

    txt1.SetFocus
    txt1.SelStart = caret_position(0)
    txt1.SelLength = caret_position(1)
End Sub

Private Sub txt2_Change()
    Dim caret_position As Variant

    caret_position = Array(txt2.SelStart, txt2.SelLength)

    UpdateSum

    txt2.SetFocus
    txt2.SelStart = caret_position(0)
    txt2.SelLength = caret_position(1)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateSum()
    Dim sum As Variant
    sum = CDec(0)

    txt1.SetFocus
    If IsNumeric(txt1.Text) Then
        sum = sum + CDec(txt1.Text)
    End If

    txt2.SetFocus
    If IsNumeric(txt2.Text) Then
        sum = sum + CDec(txt2.Text)
    End If

    txtOutput.SetFocus
    txtOutput.Text = sum
End Sub
```

Comment: It is completely untrue that a control must have focus to get the value. The control must have focus to get the text property, not the value property.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The Value property is stale in event handlers, though, so you are required to use Text in this situation in order for it to work.

Comment: I am afraid that is not true, either. You need only use the text property if the control has not lost focus, and if that is the case, then the text property is available, although it may not be the final value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy that the sum box updates after a box is updated (enter, tab or such like is pressed), then this can be done without any code. First, you will need to set the format of the textboxes to be summed to numeric, then the control source of the sum box becomes:

```
=Nz([text0],0)+Nz([text2],0)+Nz([text4],0)+Nz([text6],0)+Nz([text8],0) ...
```

Note the use of Nz, it may be possible to eliminate this by setting the default value property of the various textboxes to be summed.

A large set of controls that need to be summed in this way is often an indication of an error in the design of the database. You would normally expect this kind of thing to be a separate recordset, which could more easily be summed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but Google didn't come up with much for this topic and this thread didn't really help either.  I was able to figure out a very easy way to do this, so hopefully anyone else looking for this will find this helpful.

My need was for actual text as opposed to numbers, but the same applies.

To do what the OP is asking for you'll need at least 3 textboxes.  1 is the textbox you want to have updated each time you type, 2 is the textbox you will be typing in, and 3 is a hidden textbox.

Set textbox 1 to reference the value of the hidden textbox 3 in its control source:

```
="something in my textbox " & [textbox3]
```

In the OnChange event of textbox 2 right a line that will set the value of the hidden textbox 3 to the Text property of textbox 2 that you are typing in:

```
Private Sub textbox2_Change()
    Me.textbox3.Value = Me.textbox2.Text
End Sub
```

Each time the value of the hidden textbox 3 gets updated, the calculation/reference in the displayed textbox 1 will be updated. No need to save caret locations or anything else mentioned in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in Access 2007 by using the On Lost Focus event of the text box.
Just put something like this on the On Lost focus event of each text box that you want to be added , just make sure to set the default value of each text box to 0.

Me.Totals.Value = Me.Text1.Value + Me.Text2.Value + etc..

The moment you click on the next text box or anywhere as long as it loses focus, your sum will already be on the Totals box. You may add as many text boxes as you like, just include them in the code.